# Error running Django: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyshop.settings'

Tags: python, django

I have started learning Django and I am unable to run the server.

Python and PyCharm are freshly installed I have installed Django by command `pip install Django`. After that when I run the command `python manage.py runserver` it gives me error:

> no such file and directory

so I copied the `manage.py` file and paste right under the path which was written and when I typed again it shows me this weird long error I have tried every path but it gives me an error of no such file and directory only on one path which gives me a weird long error which is

```
(venv) C:\Users\Usman Raees\PycharmProjects\pyshop>python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usman Raees\PycharmProjects\pyshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Usman Raees\PycharmProjects\pyshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Usman Raees\PycharmProjects\pyshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Usman Raees\PycharmProjects\pyshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 68, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "C:\Users\Usman Raees\PycharmProjects\pyshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\Usman Raees\PycharmProjects\pyshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\Usman Raees\PycharmProjects\pyshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\Usman Raees\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyshop.settings'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Usman Raees\PycharmProjects\pyshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Usman Raees\PycharmProjects\pyshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Usman Raees\PycharmProjects\pyshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 343, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\Usman Raees\PycharmProjects\pyshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 232, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "C:\Users\Usman Raees\PycharmProjects\pyshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 226, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "C:\Users\Usman Raees\PycharmProjects\pyshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Usman Raees\PycharmProjects\pyshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 153, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "C:\Users\Usman Raees\PycharmProjects\pyshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\Usman Raees\PycharmProjects\pyshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\Usman Raees\PycharmProjects\pyshop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\Usman Raees\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyshop.settings'

(venv) C:\Users\Usman Raees\PycharmProjects\pyshop>
```

Comment: show your project directory

Comment: You have an error in import, inside of  `manage.py` or `settings.py`

- `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyshop.settings'`

Comment: Maybe you need to install pyshop `pip install pyshop`

Comment: I have typed in a command i can see it installing but I got some sort of error on that too
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\usman raees\pycharmprojects\pyshop\venv\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\users\usman raees\pycharmprojects\pyshop\ven
v\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\USMANR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2wk9z9jq' Check the logs for full co
mmand output.

Comment: and also this one
"    TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'NoneType'
"

Answer (score 1):

python manage.py relies of configurations in the settings.py file. Check that you still have settings.py, you might have deleted it my mistake. Thats worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Since you just started learning . create a new Django project in python (pycharm professional)  and start the app again and do not copy manage.py file anywhere.
also run the

```
$ django-admin.py startproject Yourprojectname
```

before you run the

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: I have followed your instructions i have created new project installed django and tried to runserver it gives me following error
"
(venv) C:\Users\Usman Raees\PycharmProjects\usmanproject>python manage.py runserver
C:\Users\Usman Raees\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Comment: Try running the command  "cd YOUR PROJECTAPP NAME"  and then run the "python manage.py runserver" again .